# How can I remove an item from a list, and assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, list

For some background if you're interested, I have a bit of experience in python but I haven't touched it in a couple of years - I mainly used basic but im looking to learn more of python.

I am trying to program a card based game, where items from a list (the deck of cards) are dealt out to players. I understand that this is usually bad practice, but I have created 5 "card slots" for each player which I am trying to move the card from the bottom of the list (deck) into this slot, this would make the rest of the game much simpler to program.

```
#import and shuffle cards
with open("deck.txt") as f:
        cards = f.readlines()

random.shuffle(cards)

#move bottom card to first slot (p1c1 stands for person 1 card 1)

p1c1 = cards(0)
cards.remove(a[0])
```

I am being given this error line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/harry/OneDrive/Documents/python/21.py", line 41, in <module>
    p1c1 = int(cards(0))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Probably you mean `cards[0]` instead of `cards(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy way - does assignment and removes item all at once.

```
p1c1 = cards.pop(0)
```

& the comments are right, to index a list you need to use square brackets.

Comment: Cheers, this worked great! Is there a simple rule for when square brackets are used, or do I just need to learn each individual case. It is a bit confusing that pop doesn't need them while removing and assingment do.

Comment: Hi @Imperdius. I can see how that might be confusing. It will be clearer after you get a bit more familiar with Python. Functions and methods (like `readlines` and `pop`) are called with their arguments in parentheses. Lists like `cards` are indexed using square brackets to indicate which element or elements are to be selected (look up 'slicing' in the Python documentation for all the detail on that). Lists like `cards` can also have methods, like `pop`, which operate on the list. I think if you read some of the documentation about lists in Python it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The `pop` function (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)) takes an index, and removes it while returning that item.

```
p1c1 = cards.pop(0)
```

Also note that to access a certain item in a list you use square brackets - so here's your now-working approach:

```
p1c1 = cards[0]
cards.remove(a[0])
```